# Why is my Image not displaying images as I've specified - In Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, pfimageview

So I have a `PFQueryTableViewController` where date is populated to it from Parse. I have a separate `CustomTableViewCell.swift` file which manages my cell layout.

The table displays lists of films, along with an poster image for that film. The image is declared as:

```
@IBOutlet weak var cellFilmImage: PFImageView!
```

in the `CustomTableViewCell.swift` file.

I have set constraints to the image in storyboard, for the image to be 95x140:

[image]

And I've also set the view mode to be Aspect fill:

[image]

I've added a border to my ImageView - which is light gray.

Issue: If I put a larger image there, it doesn't really respond to the settings that I've told it. See a screenshot below of what happens when I set the image to be larger:

[image]

You can see the gray outline of the ImageView, but why does the Image not sit inside the view?

Thanks in advance, let me know if you need to see any more of my code/settings.

Comment: Did you set your `imageView.clipsToBounds = true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you didn't set your `imageView.clipsToBounds = true`

Or set it from attributes inspector -> check **Clip Subviews** (Bottom of the image :] )

[image]

Comment: Such a simple fix, will remember this for next time, thanks!